# How can I view screenshots embedded in emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, screenshot

I regularly receive screenshots pasted into emails by users. Outlook 2010 will resize the image to fit the reading pane, as you can see in my sample screenshot below. In fact, I've obfuscated everything legible, but I've not needed to touch the embedded image, from which I can garner no useful information.

[image]

The problem is that I appear to have no easy way to either view the image at 100%, or zoom into it, or anything. I have to right click, save as, and then navigate to the folder and open it in an image previewer.

Is there some easier way to view these images? Ideally I'd like to be able to double-click on them and have a window I can pan-and-zoom them in, but I'll settle for a context menu option or similar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Open the email and select Actions -> Edit Message

It will now display as it was originally sized.

[image]

Comment: I do this frequently.  When in edit mode, you have the option to crop the image as well.  For example, you can take off the 2nd monitor's picture, since you probably won't ever need that.  This way the image in the email will be more legible in the future (w/o having to go to edit mode again).

Comment: In case "Edit Message" is not visible in the ribbon, you can also forward the message. In this editor, zooming images is also possible.

Comment: Though a bit counterintuitive (why does this work _only_ in edit mode?), this works for me. Thank you & +1.